# Why does Hadoop mapper and reducer take class name and not objects?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have just started using Hadoop and I see that while setting mappers, reducers and anything else in `job.set*()` it always asks for a class name. Why not an object of that class?

I am sure this must have been done for a reason. Would someone care to mention the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you might have observed, the jobs in Hadoop are executed in distributed manner by the map-reduce framework.

So the actual job will be executed by dividing the efforts into multiple mappers and reducers, where each map/reduce job are actually a Java process which will be executed by task containers on many random nodes in the cluster.

The settings we mention in job configuration are only specifications about the job. As per this settings the required Mapper/Reducer instances will be created on the random JVM task containers.

It will not be efficient to convey the instantiated map/reduce objects from the job config to every distributed node's task container where the actual map/reduce tasks will be executed, instead such instances can be created on the containers on demand as per the job settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice one. I am also thinking for reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question I presume that you are looking for an object which is not visible to you.

Here in the example you are looking for a `MAPPER object` but you didnt find `NEW` keyword any where in the program.

So to sum it up. How `A.class` is converting into `A a = new A();` ? And `WHY?`

To tell you in simple words, you cannot do any thing without having an object in java or hadoop.

Therefore behind the scenes objects are created for the mentioned class for the program execution. At high level we can say that this mechanism is inbuilt in hadoop to take care of object creation on need basis.

And at a little higher level they use `JAVA Reflection API` to do this operations seamlessly under the hood.

Why this is required? -- `THE REASONS`

Because we dont know the ANSWERS for following questions in real time:

1. What is the file size? `Number of Mappers` are based on this information.
2. How many input splits (some objects are based on this) ?
3. How many key/value pairs for both INPUT and OUTPUT (some more objects here)?
4. mapper/reducer/etc. (other X.class inputs and releted objects)

As we dont know

`How many(total number) Objects are needed?` and

`When(execution time in program) they are needed?`

we need to rely on a higher end API like reflection to handle them at runtime.

That `Reflection API used by HADOOP` is responsible to provide the `OBJECT` for the input `CLASS` based on need of the hour.

Hope this clarifies.